# MySQL Web User permissions Access denied

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a web user account for MySQL, but haven’t able to get it working right. My user is **webusr** with password **WebUser** and the database is **books**.

I created the user in phpMyAdmin with SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE only. When I run my PHP line `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'webusr', 'WebUser', 'books');` it fails with the message `“Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'webusr'@'localhost' (using password: YES)”`

[image: phpMyAdmin]
[image: phpMyAdmin2]

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. The Database also has the same permissions setup. I am on a Windows PC using EasyPHP. I tried the setup with the **root** user without password and the code seems to work fine.

Comment: Did you set user password? Try connecting without password and see what will happen..

Comment: Tried without a password and even deleted the user and recreated without a password, still get the same error.

Comment: Can you login on the console using `$ mysql -u webusr -p` and the password you have set? I'm also doubting whether `GRANT` should indeed be `No`; I think you should grant privileges in order to use them.

Comment: I get: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'webusr'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0):

1: Try using PDO instead of mySQLi [Why bother using PDO? click to read.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) 
 
2: For now, try this:

```html
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'webusr', 'WebUser', 'books');
```

instead of this:

```html
$db = new mysqli('localhost', webusr, WebUser, books);
```

Comment: I forgot to put the single quotes in my question. I have edited my question. Still doesn't work.

Comment: try using double quotes instead of single and let me know.

Comment: No. Since I am using EasyPHP to test, I used the **root** user without password and works, using the same code. I even tried granting **webusr** all privileges and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not matching the host field. In MySQL, the wildcard host `%` does not match socket connections, for those you need the host `localhost`, and if I recall correctly some versions don't even match 127.0.0.1 to `%`.

Since you're telling mysqli to use socket connections (by connecting to host localhost), and your user host field is not 'localhost', you're not able to connect. Edit your existing user and change the host to 'localhost' if you don't need tcp connections or add a new user with host 'localhost' if you want to continue to allow tcp connections (for instance, if you have an application on a different machine).